# How to re-render previous page when validating form

Tags: java, spring, forms, validation

I have a controller that renders a chores.html page with various sorts of chores.

```
@GetMapping("/chores")
public String getDueChores(Model model)
{
    var tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
    var chores = choreRepository.findByDueBefore(tomorrow);
    model.addAttribute("choresDue", chores);
    model.addAttribute("allChores", choreRepository.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("chore", new Chore());
    model.addAttribute("chores", new ArrayList<Chore>());
    return "chores";
}
```

The same page also has a form for adding a new chore. Here's the controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/chores")
public String addNewChore(@ModelAttribute @Valid Chore chore)                  
{       
    chore.setDue(LocalDate.now().plusDays(chore.getDaysBetween()));
    choreRepository.save(chore);
    return "redirect:/chores";
}
```

Now I want to display the errors if the new chore is invalid.

Attempt 1:

```
@PostMapping("/chores")
public String addNewChore(@ModelAttribute @Valid Chore chore,
                                             Errors errors)
{
    if (errors.hasErrors())
    {
        return "chores";
    }

    chore.setDue(LocalDate.now().plusDays(chore.getDaysBetween()));
    choreRepository.save(chore);
    return "redirect:/chores";
}
```

This shows the error message, but sense it's not going through the logic in the GET controller method, all the other chores on the page don't get populated.

Attempt 2:

```
@PostMapping("/chores")
public String addNewChore(@ModelAttribute @Valid Chore chore,
                          Errors errors)
{
    if (errors.hasErrors())
    {
        return "redirect:/chores";
    }

    chore.setDue(LocalDate.now().plusDays(chore.getDaysBetween()));
    choreRepository.save(chore);
    return "redirect:/chores";
}
```

This doesn't work because the error information is lost on the redirect, and the errors aren't displayed.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Here's `chores.html`, if it's relevant:

```
<body>
<h1>Due today...</h1>
<form method="post" th:action="@{/chore}" th:object="${chore}">
    <ul>
        <li th:each="chore: ${choresDue}">
            <input type="checkbox" name="choreIds" th:value="${chore.id}"/>
            <label th:text="${chore.name}"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Mark Chores Complete">
</form>

<form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/chores}" th:object="${chore}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Chore name">
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
          th:errors="*{name}">Chore name is invalid</span>
    <br>

    <input type="text" th:field="*{daysBetween}" placeholder="Do chore every # days">
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('daysBetween')}"
          th:errors="*{daysBetween}">Chore name is invalid</span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add chore">
</form>

<hr>
<h1>All Chores</h1>
<form th:method="delete" th:action="@{/deleteChore}" th:object="${chore}">
<ul>
    <li th:each="chore: ${allChores}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="choreIds" th:value="${chore.id}"/>
        <label th:text="${chore.name} + ' every ' + ${chore.daysBetween} + ' days'"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete selected chores">
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to add `Errors` to the `Model`.

```
@PostMapping("/chores")
public String addNewChore(@ModelAttribute @Valid Chore chore,
                          Errors errors,
                          Model model)
{
    if (errors.hasErrors())
    {
        model.addAttribute("error", errors);
        var tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);
        var chores = choreRepository.findByDueBefore(tomorrow);
        model.addAttribute("choresDue", chores);
        model.addAttribute("allChores", choreRepository.findAll());
        return "chores";
    }

    chore.setDue(LocalDate.now().plusDays(chore.getDaysBetween()));
    choreRepository.save(chore);
    return "redirect:/chores";
}
```